# Generate CFG of android application - practical way

Tags: android, analysis

I have a question with respect to create Control Flow Graph (CFG) with Androgurad tool or other tools.
Browsing the Internet I have noticed, there are some approaches to create CFG of an android application. for example, some tools such as smali CFG generator https://code.google.com/p/smali-cfgs/, APKInspector,  dexter and many other tools written by android security experts... .Also, Androguard is capable of doing that. On top of that I would like to add that I have read Androguard tutorial, and other tools' READ ME FILES and MANUALS and there is no comprehensive guide to create CFG (specially for newbies like me).

I have installed Santoku distribution  https://santoku-linux.com/ on my system to do android reverse engineering. It has some RE tools installed like Androguard, APKtool and .... I need your help to find a practical solution to generate CFG of android applications. (Preferably using these pre-installed tools :) )

I would have to say that I need CFG to feed into Machine Learning Approaches like (Kernel Method -SVM). I would really appreciate if you have any experience in this regard, share it with mme and others who might have such a question in the future :) .
Any suggestion and recommendation in a comprehensive way are welcomed.
Thanks for your assistance and support in advance.

Comment: first of all thanks for your comment, nowadays I am busy with installing APKInspector, after that I will proceed with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any useful tools that can analyze CFG easily. But recently, I read some paper that design some tools or algorithms can analyze CFG. However, unfortunately these tools are not open source. So you need to implement these tools by yourself.

To implement a CFG tool, you may need: instrumentation and CFG algorithm. I can give you some paper to refer.

Here are the papers I read:
[SIF: A Selective Instrumentation Framework for Mobile Applications](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~halfond/papers/hao13mobisys.pdf)
[Efficient Path Profiling](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/tball/papers/pathprof.pdf)
[AppInsight: Mobile App Performance Monitoring in the Wild](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/173922/appinsight.pdf)